# db2 export Data consistency

Tags: db2, export, consistency

I'm exporting a table of size around 1TB.

How do I ensure that during the export ,the data are exported from a consistent point.

Say If my export runs for 3 hrs, and during that period if any dmls happens on this particular table,
how it will affect my export.

Does my export dump will the recent dmls as well?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `WITH RR` to your select statement forces the statement to use the repeatable read isolation level – this will guarantee that your export is transactionally consistent.

For example:

```
export to file.del of del
select * from yourtable WITH RR;
```

You can read more about [isolation levels](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0004121.html) in the DB2 documentation.

Please note that doing this may have a negative impact on application concurrency (and performance) and could easily cause problems, so it may not be feasible to effectively lock a table for as long as it takes to export the contents of a 1Tb table.

If it's truly a requirement to get a transactionally consistent set of data and it's not feasible to export data like this, you could consider taking a backup of the database and restoring it on another system where you won't have other applications trying to access the database at the same time.